# Microsoft Office 365 Licensing is confused

Tags: microsoft-office, license

I've got one user here that gets a popup warning every time they run core Office Desktop apps (Word, Outlook, Excel).  It says they are unlicensed and should login.  However, if I look at the accounts settings in the apps they are already logged in.  In the O365 control panel they are set for the correct version and apps.  If they go to the office.com portal themselves it even confirms that they are licensed and logged in.  If I delete their computer authorization from O365 and have them sign in, it gets updated with that computer again, but the sign in from the app reports failure and continues to tell them they are not licensed (but if you check accounts afterwards it will show them as logged in).

I've gone so far as to deactivate the license, uninstall Office completely, and reinstall.  Every indicator in the system says they are licensed *except* for the apps themselves.  What else should I look at?

Comment: Are they also running (or have installed) other Office programs that are a different version-year?

Comment: No, all Office programs are from the same installer (this computer was recently reformatted, so it's pretty clean in general)